# Setting an element text outside server-tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

Is it possible to put `Text` in a element outside the `<form runat="server">` tag?

I'm trying to at least output my `Session` values like the user's name in a `<a>` element.

In my **login.aspx.cs** i start the session

```
Session["username"] = firstname.Text;
```

and then try to output it on other pages navigation that is outside the `<form>` tag

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-brand-centered">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="home.aspx">Home</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="account.aspx" id = "account"><!--The place where i will output--></a></li>
      <li><a href="functions/logout.aspx">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

i tried to call the `id` of the `<a>` it doesn't appear in suggestion and i started to think that its outside the server tag.
Thank you for understanding and for helping.

Comment: You can make any element `runat="server"`, not just asp controls.

Answer (score 1):

Use it like `<%# Session["username"].ToString() %>`, you need not set from code behind, you will directly access to it.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-brand-centered">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li><a href="home.aspx">Home</a></li>
   </ul>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="account.aspx" id = "account"><%# Session["username"].ToString() %></a></li>
      <li><a href="functions/logout.aspx">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: no output sir?.. i had check the session and its correct

Comment: can you please tell me what issue you have faced after change this code?

Comment: i tried this `Response.Write(Session["username"].ToString());` it makes an output but directly to the body

Comment: it didn't give an output sir.

Comment: `Response.Write(Session["username"].ToString());` will only renders text of username..

Comment: yes sir but how can i direct it to the `<a>` element?

Comment: do you need to bind user name in menu?

Comment: is there anything i need to add in the `<%@ Page>` tag sir?

Comment: What error do you get with above code? And dont say sir

Comment: thank you for helping i resolve it using this `<%Response.Write(Session["username"]);%>`

Comment: This would work without the Response.Write if you replace `<%# ... %>` with `<%= %>` where the hash tries to bind and the equals sign tries to evaluate